# overfull hbox in list of figures even if line is within page margins

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

The code below complain for an overfull hbox in the list of figure, albeit the line is well within pagemargin. How can the warning be removed? What is Latex typesetting after the number?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\makeatother
\overfullrule=5mm
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{A very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong captioooonnnnn}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tocloft sets \rightskip to 25.5pt.  Use \cftsetrmarg{0pt}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will never generate an overfull `\hbox`, at least not due to the page number.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\cftsetrmarg{0pt}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{\hspace{0pt plus \@pnumwidth}\allowbreak}
\makeatother

\overfullrule=5mm
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{A very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong captioooonnnnnnnn}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}
```

---

This solution allows the page number and only the page number all the way to the right margin.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{}
\renewcommand{\cftfigafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip
  \advance\parfillskip by -\rightskip}
\makeatletter
\cftsetrmarg{\@pnumwidth}
\makeatother

\overfullrule=5mm
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{A very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong captioooonnnnnnn}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\framebox{FIGURE}
\caption{\blindtext}
\label{figure2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```